# How to use MySQLi in a class

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I have 2 files

MySQLi.php

```
$MySQLi = new mysqli($DB_ServerName, $DB_UserName, $DB_Password, $DB_Name); 
    if($MySQLi->connect_error) 
    { 
        ... 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        ... 
    }
```

Articles.php

```
class Articles 
{ 
    public function AddArticle() 
    { 
        if ($MySQLi->query("INSERT INTO articles (Title, ArticleContent, Author) VALUES ('Title', 'Content', 'Author')") === TRUE) 
        { 
           ... 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            ... 
        } 
    } 
}
```

How can I use $MySQLi in Articles class?
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: include MySQLi.php into Articles.php

Comment: One thing you can do is to create the MySQLi object, and pass that as a parameter to the Articles class. So you'll do `$MySQLi = new mysqli(..); $acticle = new Article($MySQLi);` and in your constructor for Articles have `$this->MySQLi = $MySQLi;` as an object inside your Articles. Then you can use it in all method of that class with `$this->MySQLi ->query(...);` There are other, different ways to do it, and the goal is to include the `$MySQLi` object into the *scope* of your methods.

Comment: You could use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and already have a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you should include connection object file to another file.

Another alternative is:-

**1)** **Make connection class static to handle mysqli object.**

```
class DBConnection {
    public static $con;
}
DBConnection::$con = new mysqli(YOUR_HOST, YOUR_USER, YOUR_PASS, YOUR_DB);
```

and in other file, call it statically as below:-

```
DBConnection::$con->query(...); // execute your query
```

**2) You can also do it by creating class and object.**

```
class Connection{
  public $conn;

  function __construct($host='YOUR_HOST',$user='YOUR_USER',$pass='YOUR_PASS',$db='YOUR_DB'){
     $this->conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
  }
}
```

then create object of Connection class

```
$object = new Connection(); // pass connection params if you want to overwrite default connection params

$object->conn->query(..); // execute your query
```